# Targeting multiple elements with JSS

Tags: material-ui, jss

I am trying to target all h elements of typography mui class. Writing them one by one is annoying:

```
        typography: {
    "& h1": {
      fontWeight: "400",
    },
    "& h2": {
      fontWeight: "400",
    },
    "& h3": {
      fontWeight: "400",
    },
    "& h4": {
      fontWeight: "400",
    },
    "& h5": {
      fontWeight: "400",
    },
    "& h6": {
      fontWeight: "400",
    },
}
```

There should be a shorter syntax for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
  tyopgraphy: {
    '& h1, & h2, & h3, & h4, & h5, & h6': {
      fontWeight: '400',
    },
  },
```